# JSON callback function to show an album cover

Tags: json

I am working on a task to learn how to use JSON.  I am trying to link to spotify's API via a search, get an artists albums and show them on the webpage.  I am a beginner and do not know what I am missing in the data / callback function to create the correct html to show on my page.  If anyone has time to point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Creating the AJAX Request
//
$('#search').submit(function(event) {
  // Stop the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get The value from the form
  var SpotifyURL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/searchjsoncallback=?";
  var artist = $('#search').val();
  var artistOptions = {
    "type" : "album",
      "q" : "artisit"
  };

 function displayAlbums(data) {
      var albumHTML = '<ul>';
      $.each(data.items,function(i, album) {
         albumHTML += '<li class="albumInformation">';
         albumHTML += '<></li>';
      }); // end each
       albumHTML += '</ul>';
      $('#albums').html( albumHTML);
    }

  $.getJSON(SpotifyURL, artistOptions, displayAlbums );// end getJSON
}); // end submit function

}); // Closing Ready function
```

Comment: Have you checked out the spoify api search example? http://jsfiddle.net/UT7bQ/10/

Comment: https://labs.spotify.com/2015/03/09/understanding-spotify-web-api/